# GMP rounding modes

Tags: gmp, arbitrary-precision

Is there any way to change the rounding mode when doing operations with GMP? Or do I have to use MPFR for that?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you should use MPFR if you want to control rounding.

The good news is it's relatively trivial to initialize an mpfr_t from an mpf_t, so you can throw it in where you need the rounding control, if you don't want to convert everything over.

See: http://www.mpfr.org/mpfr-current/mpfr.html